# Android Studio making this blue line at the screen's top disappear

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I'm sorry for the unclear title , it's just that I don't the name of this thing.
Anyway , here is a picture of the main screen of the app:

[image]

I want to remove the blue bar/title/line at the top (where it shows the time and battery..)
If I can't remove it than atleast modify it by changing it color to black of something that suits better the background of the layout.
Thank you,
Noam

Comment: You may try changing the theme

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The blue bar at the top is called "status bar". You can control it's colour by setting `android:colorPrimaryDark` (or `colorPrimaryDark` if you're using an AppCompat theme).

If you started your project from an Android Studio template then you should have a `styles.xml` file with `AppTheme` defined. One of the lines inside should look like this:

```
<item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primaryDark</item>
```

You can either change the value directly here to something like `@android:color/black` or go into `colors.xml` where `primaryDark` is defined and change it to black there.

If you want to hide the status bar completely, see [Lino's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37628677/1402641).

Comment: Thank you all for your answers. I eventually decided to simply change the color so I accept Marcin answer.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can hide the status bar programmatically.
Here are the steps for Android 4.1 and higher:

```
View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
// Hide the status bar.
int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
// Remember that you should never show the action bar if the
// status bar is hidden, so hide that too if necessary.
ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
actionBar.hide();
```

For more detail (and lower Android versions) see: https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/status.html

Answer (score 0):

That blue line is called `StatusBar`.

There are two ways to do it

if you want to do it programatically:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);
    }
}
```

Or else in your AndroidManifest.xml file:

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using AppCompatActivity in 3.0.1 solved the issue by adding in manifest:

```
application android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
```